# How to handle Laravel to Vue.js boolean values

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

I've got an input field that looks like the following :

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in collection">
   ...
   <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          v-model="item.activated" 
          @change="toggleSwitch(item.resource_url, 'activated', item)">
   >
   ...
</tr>
```

The `collection` is an array containing several keys, activated is one of them. `activated` is equal to `1` or `0` as the data is coming from a mysql database. The problem is that the input field is always set to true in this case, even if the `activated` is equal to 1 or 0.

Now, I tried writing the v-model like so to fix the issue :

```
v-model="!!+item.activated"
```

as by adding `!!+` I'd convert the integer value to a boolean and use that. That fixes the issue, but creates another. The other issue I get by doing so is when I try to change my checked input I get an error :

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: false
admin.js:120238 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'activated' in false
```

The `toggleSwitch` method looks like this :

```
toggleSwitch: function toggleSwitch(url, col, row) {
    var _this8 = this;

    axios.post(url, row).then(function (response) {
        _this8.$notify({ type: 'success' });
    }, function (error) {
        row[col] = !row[col];
        _this8.$notify({ type: 'error' });
    });
},
```

I'm new to Vue.js, any idea how to debug this and where could my problem be coming from? I'll gladly give any additional info.

Edit :

Here's my component

```
Vue.component('profile-edit-profile-form', {
    mixins: [AppForm],
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                ...
                activated:  false ,
                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: May you show how you retrieve your `collection` in this component please?

Comment: @Shizzen83 yes sorry, erm the default value of collection is null, and I fill it using an ajax laravel/vue request from my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use AJAX to populate your `collection`, then you should convert your `0` and `1` strings to booleans in your AJAX callback before injecting them into your component. Or even better you could convert them directly from your controller, by the way you directly get `true`|`false`

```
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    if(entry.hasOwnProperty("activated"))
        entry.activated = !!+entry.activated
});
```

Comment: That's a good workaround, thank you for suggesting it, I'll surely use this if there's no other answer. The values I get are indeed strings and are not seen as integers.

Comment: You should take a look to https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting . With a `boolean` cast and if you use an Eloquent model, it would be the best way as the data is automatically converted when you retrieve it from the database.

Answer (score 2):

my recommendation is:

- Database column "activated" tinyint(1)
- in laravel model use $cast array to cast "activated" to "boolean"
- in vue use native type boolean for form.activated with true and false

Laravel Model:

```
protected $casts = [
'created_at' => 'datetime',
'updated_at' => 'datetime',
'minimum' => 'float',
'maximum' => 'float',
'step' => 'float',
'minItems' => 'integer',
'maxItems' => 'integer',
'uniqueItems' => 'boolean',
];
```

Vue:

```
<b-form-radio-group id="uniqueItems" v-model="formData.uniqueItems" :options="optionsBoolean" name="uniqueItems" :/>

optionsBoolean (){
            return [
                { text: 'Yes'), value: true },
                { text: 'No'), value: false }
            ]
        }
```